# Moodle Quiz REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, http, moodle

**Has anyone figured out how to use the Moodle function '*mod_quiz_process_attempt*'?**

I am exploring the Moodle Webservices (REST API), in order to request a Quiz that has been set up on Moodle. I am developing an Android App, through which users can attempt a Moodle Quiz (Questions are of type **Multiple Choice** only).

I have already figured out how to start a quiz attempt and retrieve the quiz data, but I couldn't find out, how to save and process the selected answers on Moodle through the provided REST API.

The Moodle function '*mod_quiz_process_attempt*' should be responsible for this. According to the Moodle documentation the function needs an argument called 'data', which is an Array of Name-Value-Objects.

```
General structure

Default to "Array
(
)
" //the data to be saved
list of ( 
  object {
    name string   //data name
    value string   //data value
  } 
 )
```

My questions is: Which '**data**' (which names and values), do I need to pass to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You must use :

```
mod_quiz_save_attempt
```

Processes save requests during the quiz.This function is intended for the quiz auto-save feature in moodle mobile app

check the [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this function needs a 'data' argument too. What kind of data should I save (What name? What value?)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod_quiz_get_attempt_review` function.

This takes input an attempt number and passes the entire attempt as the rest to a rest call.

```
$username = array('attemptid' => $val );//$val contains attempt ID.
$params = array( 'courseids' => $username);

$resp = json_decode(($curl->post($serverurl,$username)),true);
```

`$resp['questions']` gives the details of the questions. You can process all the questions going in a for each loop.

Check documentation of this function for better understanding of the functionalities you can retrieve.

Answer (score -1):

This is how to set up the data for processing an attempt :
[Structure of http request to send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JieQ4.jpg)

```
$data = array();
$data[0]['name'] = "q16:1_answer";
$data[0]['value'] = 1;
$data[1]['name'] = "q16:1_:sequencecheck";
$data[1]['value'] = 1;
$data[2]['name'] = "q16:2_answer";
$data[2]['value'] = 1;
$data[3]['name'] = "q16:2_:sequencecheck";
$data[3]['value'] = 1;
$data[4]['name'] = "q16:3_answer";
$data[4]['value'] = 0;
$data[5]['name'] = "q16:3_:sequencecheck";
$data[5]['value'] = 1;
$data[6]['name'] = "q16:4_answer";
$data[6]['value'] = 0;
$data[7]['name'] = "q16:4_:sequencecheck";
$data[7]['value'] = 1;
```